How to Use select in createQuery with Svelte Query to Process Fetched Data?
I'm using @tanstack/svelte-query with Svelte and want to process the data fetched by createQuery, similar to how select works in React Query's useQuery. How can I achieve this in Svelte?
This code is not working
const query = createQuery({
    queryKey: key,
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await actionOption.request(keyId)
      return response
    },
    select: (data) => {
      return data.data
    },
    staleTime: 0,
    ...queryOptions
  })

